# ggplot facet_wrap error when using `ROW` as column name

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I have a data.table I'm trying to plot facets with ggplot and I'm getting the error listed below. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
require(data.table, ggplot2)

dt <- as.data.table(read.table(h=T, 
text="ROW mode resbin V1
0   RD   50.0  0
1   RD   50.0  0
2   RD   50.0  0
0   RD   33.3  0
1   RD   33.3  0                  
1   PV    7.5  1
2   PV    7.5  0
0   PV    6.0  1
1   PV    6.0  1
2   PV    6.0  1"))


ggplot(dt, aes(x = factor(resbin), y = V1, group=1)) + 
geom_point(aes(color=factor(mode)), size=3) +
geom_line() +
facet_wrap(~factor(ROW), ncol=2)

#Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : 
#At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something funny is going on that I don't fully understand. This seems to work for me:

```
dt <- as.data.table(read.table(h=T, 
text="grp mode resbin V1
0   RD   50.0  0
1   RD   50.0  0
2   RD   50.0  0
0   RD   33.3  0
1   RD   33.3  0                  
1   PV    7.5  1
2   PV    7.5  0
0   PV    6.0  1
1   PV    6.0  1
2   PV    6.0  1"))


ggplot(dt, aes(x = factor(resbin), y = V1)) + 
geom_point(aes(color=factor(mode)), size=3) +
geom_line(aes(group = 1)) +
facet_wrap(~grp, ncol=2)
```

I seemed to need to change the column name *and* remove `factor()` from it. But I only tested this briefly.

Comment: I tried changing the name of the from "mode" to "my.mode" and removing the factors and it still blew up. I also prefer reading the data in using as.data.frame(). This is a good one...

Comment: That worked. Thanks for the help.  I'll have to remember that ggplot doesn't like columns named `ROW`.

Comment: @NathanG Disliking `ROW` as a column name seems _very_ suspicious to me. I'm planning on asking around to verify that that's a bug.

Comment: other names that it's not going to like are `COL` and `PANEL` https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/3af088f2943d43d8af537f6eb807f7164f0362c8/R/facet-layout.r#L54

Comment: and `SCALE_X`, `SCALE_Y`, `AXIS_X` and `AXIS_Y`. See https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/838